# Audiotoggle cordova plugin not working in android 9

Tags: android, cordova, webrtc

I have Cordova app and I have android platform 8. App uses JQuery Verto library for getting remote audio stream and play it in audio html element.

By default `Verto` find one speaker device with `id = 'default'`. Next after playing audio I need use EARPIECE device.

In android 8 I use audiotoggle-plugin for it(use AudioToggle.setAudioMode(AudioToggle.EARPIECE) method) and it worked normal. But on Android 9, it doesn't work.

However, When remote stream is playing through the default speaker, if I start another app (example YouTube and play video) and then stop it and get back to my app, audiotoggle-plugin work normal.

Any ideas?

Here is the plugin's link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-audiotoggle

Comment: Can you try this fork: `ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/abeimler/audio-toggle.git` (remove the old one first)

Comment: It doesn't work for me(

Comment: Did you try other devices?

Comment: No, Now I have only Samsung Galaxy S8+ on android 9

Comment: Can would be problem with android audiofocus?

Comment: Maybe. Can you create a repo so we can play with it?

Comment: The problem was in JQuery Verto library but not in the cordova plugin. When library tries to modify sound quality, it responses error. I just disabled modifying sound quality and it started works great.